# how to remove inline css from string in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I want to remove inline css from string in javascript:

```
var str = "p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 12.0px 'Helvetica Neue'}
span.Apple-tab-span {white-space:pre} This is sample text";
```

I want

```
str = "This is sample text";
```

Could you please help me how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your string has always this pattern: The text after a css definition, you can try this:

```
const str = "p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 12.0px 'Helvetica Neue'} span.Apple-tab-span {white-space:pre} This is sample text"

const lastOccurrence = str.lastIndexOf('}')

console.log(str.substr(lastOccurrence+1, str.length))
```

Comment: i am not sure this will be the same every time. Because this is happening only when i copy some text from notepad on MAC machine.

Comment: Ok, so you have to figure out a pattern before. It is not possible to extract a string from another without having a pattern.